# Limit of maximum of a function on an interval

Tags: analysis, limits, functions

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a  bounded function such that $f(x) \to 0$, as $x \to \infty$. Prove  that $$\max\limits_{u \in [x/2,x]}f(u) \to 0$$ as $x \to \infty$.

I need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $\epsilon > 0$.

You know that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$$

This means that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $M>0$ such that $$x' > M\implies |f(x)|<\epsilon$$

Now, let's say I tell you that $\frac{x}{2} > M$, and let's say I tell you that $u\in\left[\frac x2, x\right]$.

- Can you say anything about $f(u)$?
- From that, can you say anything about $\max_{u\in\left[\frac x2, x\right]} f(u)$?

Comment: Yes, I can write the proof now. Thank you!

Comment: @kmitov Notice how, in my answer, I didn't really give you any new information. Sometimes, all it takes to solve a question is to slowly and carefully write down everything you know, then ask yourself the correct question.